# Why Are Balances Not Displaying On An Imported Wallet in Mist? (It Does Appear on Etherscan)

Tags: mist, ether, the-dao, balances, import

I just got a new computer, installed Mist 0.8.8, synced the entire blockchain, then copy-pasted a UTC wallet file from my old computer into my new computer's %appdata%>keystore directory. The wallet appears in Mist when I run it. However, all balances are 0. It should have both Ether and DAO Tokens in it (DAO Tokens have already been added to watchlist). When I lookup the address on Etherscan, it shows the correct balances.

How could this occur? How can it be fixed so I make transfers and call contracts in Mist?

Comment: Did you check your mist browser is really on the _latest_ block?

Comment: It's currently only ~100,000 blocks behind. So that shouldn't make too much of a difference since the DAO Tokens were distributed many more block heights before that.

Comment: Well than you have to check back when you are fully synchronized. It usually only takes a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the block height of a transaction has been reached, Mist still may not display balances correctly. Wait until The blockchain is synced 100%.